# Query for OR condition

Tags: elasticsearch

> I need elasticsearch query for following sql

```
SELECT document FROM  brand WHERE  brandprivacy=false or (brandid=['1','3'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with this query:

```
POST brand/_search
{
  "_source": ["document"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "brandprivacy": false
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "brandid": [
              "1",
              "3"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I also suggest that you should take the time to go through the [Query DSL guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) and learn the different queries that ES supports.

Comment: if i need both brandprivacy as well as my brandid details . what i need to do . (i.e union of sets )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "details". Can you explain please?

Comment: sorry thats above mentioned brandid 1,3 information from DB.

Comment: Both constraints are in my query, please look again more carefully.

Comment: val . I didnt get brandid 1,3 results . from your code i only get brandprivacy false results . I need both values .

Comment: You specified an OR constraint in your question. Do you need an AND constraint instead?